# AngularJS event handler inside directive not firing / parametric event name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, event-handling

I jotted down [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/sks0nmtz/) in order to replicate my scenario.
I basically have this view loaded via `ui-router` inside a `<div>` on my page, and a directive which loads it with `$state.go`. The directive's controller *should* be listening for an event named `myEvent:<scope.$id>` (in the fiddle it's `myEvent:2`, for instance), while the external view *should* fire just that event since it's loaded with the proper `$stateParams.scopeId` (as can be seen from the respective `$scope.ev` properties). Furthermore, I am using `$scope.$emit` since I gather, from the fact that the external view has a higher `$scope.$id`, that the event should be propagated upwards and eventually reach the directive's scope and be caught, or am I missing something? Cheers.

**UPDATE:** I managed to get it working by adding this:

```
.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.$root.$on("myEvent:2", function(e, data) {
        $scope.$broadcast("myEvent:2", data);
    });
}])
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/sks0nmtz/2/)), since I figured the external view's `scope` is probably not a child of the directive's `scope`; rather, they share a common ancestor, and certainly the `$rootScope` will do just fine. So I am `$emit`ting the event all the way to the `$rootScope` and `$broadcast`ing it back downwards. The issue now is that I had to hard-code the event name which is a major deal breaker, for I have no prior knowledge of the directive's `scope.$id`; is there no way of having parametric or regex-based event names such as:

```
.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.$root.$on("myEvent:(\d+)", function(e, data) {
        $scope.$broadcast("myEvent:" + RegExp.$1, data);
    });
}])
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/sks0nmtz/3/). The trick it to `$emit` a generic event from the view, and pass the proper `$scope.$id` into the event data. On the `$rootScope`, extract the `id` and use to form the proper event name for repropagation.